# URL Rewrite - rewrite all requests unless they are for an existing application

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

In IIS, would like to rewrite all requests at the Default Web Site level to mainApplication unless they are requests for otherApp, or thisApp, or thatApp and so on.

Is there a way to do this without adding a condition for each of the other applications? Some variation on "is a directory"?

Comment: Typically, you would have separate IIS "applications" for each website. So requests for any particular website would go to the proper place already. (You shouldn't need to rewrite a request because it would already go to the right place.) You can do the same for mainApplication too, and still not need any redirects. Then you would set up all other requests to be ignored, or setup mainApplication to be the catch-all.

Comment: I actually only have the Default web site, with (say) 4 IIS applications. One of these is the "master" application--any requests that are not for one of the others should go to this application. Right now, I have a rule that redirects to the master application, then conditions to exclude each of the applications (including master, as in don't redirect to master if it is a request for master). I'm looking for a way to say "redirect to master UNLESS it is a request for an existing application" without having to list them.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was suggesting. Move all 4 applications out of the default website- you want 4 separate applications. Set up host headers for the first 3, and leave the host header blank for the main application, which will act like the catch-all. More info can be found here: http://serverfault.com/questions/279688/how-to-create-a-catch-all-subdomain-in-iis-7-5

Comment: I guess we should clarify, how are your applications distinguished? Are they different domains or different subdirectories? Can you provide example URLs for the different applications?

Comment: @TTT good point. They are all using the same domain name. I want to have a "Default app" to which every request gets routed to *unless it is a request for an existing application* (that is the part I thought would be easy, similar to how "folders" are handled)

Comment: Oh and I should point out that this is an existing setup, so URL changes are not really an option. I'm looking to make it simpler for the sake of support and documentation.

Comment: So how are you distinguishing the apps? It should still work with subdirectories. SomeDomain.com/ = main app, SomeDomain.com/app1, SomeDomain.com/somedir1/somedir2/app2, SomeDomain.com/somedir1/somedir2/app2/somedir3/app3, etc. Anything that matches will automatically match the proper application. The only issue I can think of is if your main level domain is not the main "default" app.